# Protection and damage prevention spells

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Scenario-> I have pro-red creature like [Burrenton forge-tender](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burrenton%20forge-tender).  I cast [Divine Deflection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Divine%20Deflection) for 2, targeting the forgetender and my opponent.  I then cast [Pyroclasm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pyroclasm)  Does the 2 damage to the forgetender get prevented by Divine Deflection or by the protection from red?  Does my opponent take 2 damage from Divine Deflection?

Also, if the damage would just be redirected, would it work the same?  For example, replace Divine Deflection in the last scenario with [Harm's Way](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Harm%27s%20Way).  Is the damage prevented by protection from red or is it redirected?

Comment: Note that Divine Deflection only has one target: whatever the damage should be dealt to after prevention. It's the same with Harm's Way.